# The toggle drop down in navbar is not touch responsive on mobile phones?

Tags: html, css

The navbar's toggle button drops down to reveal the sections on a computer
when I activate it by decreasing the window width, but when I get on the website through my mobile, the button acts like an image and doesn't drop down. I believe this is because the button isn't touch-responsive, so how can I efficiently make it a button on mobile phones?

Here is my code so far:

EDIT: PER REQUEST, I HAVE ADDED MORE CODE. THIS IS THE HTML HEAD SECTION:

```
<head>
  <title>****</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="/assets/images/logo.png" type="image/x-icon">

    <!--fontawesome, bootstrap, jquery-->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
    <!--/fontawesome, bootstrap, jquery-->

    <script src="/assets/smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>
  <link href="/assets/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <nav class="row navbar">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-bars"></i>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="/assets/images/logo.png" width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> ******</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a data-scroll class="nav-item nav-link" href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a data-scroll class="nav-item nav-link" href="#getinvolved">Get Involved</a></li>
            <li><a data-scroll class="nav-item nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 11px 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #000;
}

.navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-brand:focus, .navbar-brand:active {
  color: #000;
}

.navbar-brand img{
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px
}

#navbar a, #navbar a:hover, #navbar a:focus, #navbar a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  cursor: default;

}
```

Comment: are you using Bootstrap or any other code?

Comment: yes, I am using bootstrap and smoothscroll.js

Comment: do you have all the jquery code under the footer before the </body> tag?  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Yes, I have the links. The drop down menu works fine on the computer, but on a mobile, it acts like an image and doesn't drop down. I believe the issue isn't the jquery, but the fact that the button isn't touch-responsive on a touchscreen device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you missed including jQuery? Your code is working for me, here is the 
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yL6m3po5/).

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="row navbar">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">uuuuu<i class="fa fa-lg fa-bars"></i>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="" width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> ******</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a data-scroll class="nav-item nav-link" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a data-scroll class="nav-item nav-link" href="#getinvolved">Get Involved</a></li>
        <li><a data-scroll class="nav-item nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Works for me in the mobile as well. Please post more code.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works on a computer no matter the width of the window, but when I get on a mobile phone, on the website, the button acts like an image. To understand what I am saying, access your fiddle through a mobile phone. The button acts like an image and doesn't drop down when touched.

Comment: That is very frustrating. I went on two other phones and, on both of them, the button didn't drop down, on safari and chrome. I have added the head section to my question. Thanks for your help so far.